# How to open dialog with edit text box when an item is selected from drop down list

Tags: android, dialog

I am trying to build an android app in which I make a `dropdownlist`. When a specific item is  selected from  the drop-down, a dialog box with edit text and a button should open. How can I do this?

spiner.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Spinner spinner1, spinner2;
    private Button button;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        addItemsOnSpinner2();
        addListenerOnButton();
        addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection();
    }

    public void addItemsOnSpinner2() {

        spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        List list = new ArrayList();
        list.add("Item 1");
        list.add("Item 2");
        list.add("Item 3");
        list.add("Item 4");
        ArrayAdapter dataAdapter = new
                ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }

    public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection() {
        spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());
    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        "Result : " +
                                "\nSpinner 1 : " + String.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItem()) +
                                "\nSpinner 2 : " + String.valueOf(spinner2.getSelectedItem()),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        });
    }

    public class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView parent, View view, int pos, long id)
        {

            Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Selected Country : " +
                    parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Formatting your code for StackOverflow would go a long ways towards getting an answer

Comment: @Tanis.7x Too true, or you could help them out and format it for them. :)

Comment: I usually do for short code samples, but I tend to shy away form the longer code dumps.

Comment: public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection() {
        spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());

it should have been spinner2 i guess
    }